# How to avoid spelling mistakes while using Pothana2000 font file for a textview?

Tags: java, android, fonts, textview

I'm trying to set the font for a textview using Pothana2000. I'm retrieving the unicode from json. everything is decoded fine. but, while setting into the textview using Typeface class, i'm getting spelling mistakes. How to correct this?